# Can excel organize my data into groupings?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

First off, my data sample:

```
EZ LOADER       1
FAIRMONT MOBI   1
FARMALL TRACT   3
FORD            5
FORD 700        1
FORD F-150      1
FOUR DOO        1
FOUR WINNS      1
GENERAL         3
GENERAL MOBIL   1
GMC             1
```

I have over 12k records like this. What I'm wondering is if I can possibly throw a CSV or list of "common" car makers at the list, and somehow cut them in to their own column or spreadsheet.

basically by the end of this I need to have the whole thing sorted as "car" "tractor" "other" etc.

Answer (score 4):

First create a [pivot table](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-or-delete-a-pivottable-or-pivotchart-report-HP010089893.aspx) from your data, and then use the [Sort](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/pivottbls/sort2010.php) option to sort your data.